# Чергування приголосних у топонімах (назви міст тощо)

Tags: відмінювання, чергування, приголосні

Це питання найбільш актуальне для українців, що живуть у Німеччині, оскільки багато топонімів закінчуються на -берг, -бург, -бах, -ах. Я чув такі варіанти:

*у Гайдельбергу - у Гайдельберзі*

*в Айзенаху - в Айзенасі*

*в Гамбургу - в Гамбурзі*

Як говорити правильно?

Answer (score 2):

**Коротко.** Основе закінчення — ***~і***, а тому з чергуваннями приголосних. Втім можна писати з ***~у*** і навіть ***~ові***, що без чергування приголоснних, але це не рекомендовано.

---

Тут чергування приголосних залежні насамперед від закінчення до місцевого відмінку, котре може бути як ***~у***, ***~і*** — що впливає на зміну приголосного — і, аби було ще веселіше, ***~ові***. Наприклад один словник від УМІФ:а також [наводить](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%90%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85) [*в*] *Айзенахові* з підписом, що це мова якраз про місто. Тому аби відповісти на це питання, варто розглянути саме це. Більшість наведених вами слів — другої відміни, хоча чергування можуть відбуватися і в інших відмінах, наприклад *Африка*, що належить до першої відміни, стає [*в*] *Африці*. Витяги беру з правописа 2019 року.

> [**§ 152. Відмінювання географічних назв**](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=188)
>
> 1. Українські, а також іншомовні географічні назви з іменниковими закінченнями відмінюємо переважно як звичайні іменники I, II, III відмін:
>
>    II відміна: *Буг* — *на Бу́зі* (й *по Бу́гу*); *Владивосто́к* — *у Владивосто́ці* (*у Владивосто́ку*); … *Луга́нськ* — *у Луга́нську*; *Токма́к* — *у Токмацí* (*у Токмако́*); …

Як можна побачити, виняток лише назва міста, що збіжне з структурою прикметника, що можуть мати свої правила, наприклад *§ 150. Географічні назви з прикметниковими закінченнями*, тому на них можна не звертати увагу. Решта ж мають обі форми — ***~у*** і ***~і***, що спричиняє чергування. Решта назв, де неможливе чергування, мають за основу лише закінчення ***~і***:

> *Га́йсин* — *у Га́йсині*; *Ду́бно* — *у Ду́бні*; *Ки́їв* — *у Ки́єві*; … ; *Львів* — *у Льво́ві*; … *Псков* — *у Пскові*, … *У́жгород* — *в У́жгороді*.

Тому якщо ви прихильник мати однакове закінчення до місцевого відмінку, то з ***~і*** — бажанїше, але це не обовязково.

---

Про всяк розгляньмо інші правила, одне з яких вже згадане вище:

> **II Відміна**
>
> **А. Однина**
>
> [**§ 82. Місцевий відмінок**](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=121)
>
> У місцевому відмінку однини іменники другої відміни
> мають закінчення **-і** (**-ї**), **-ові**, **-еві** (**-єві**), **-у** (**-ю**).
>
> 1. Закінчення **-і** (після голосного та апострофа — **-ї**) мають:
>
>    - іменники чол. роду (переважно безсуфіксні) — назви
>      неістот: …
>
>      Примітка 1. Деякі іменники цього зразка можуть мати варіантні
>      закінчення **-і** (**-ї**) та **-у** (**-ю**), що залежить від місця наголосу в них: …

І, схоже, це є основним правилом для нашого випадка. Бо для ***~у*** бажано односкладові слова або копатися в примітках:

> 2. Закінчення **-у** (після голосного — **-ю**) мають:
>
>    - іменники чол. роду односкладових основ із закінченням
>      **-у** (**-ю**) в родовому відмінку, якщо наголос у місцевому відмін-
>      ку переходить з основи на закінчення: …
>
>      Примітка 1. Із прийменником по деякі іменники набувають варіан-
>      тних закінчень **-у** (**-ю**) та **-і** (**-ї**): …
>
>      Примітка 2. Із прийменниками **в** (**у**) деякі іменники також набува-
>      ють варіантних закінчень **-у** (**-ю**) та **-і** (**-ї**): …

Або бажано [переважно] бути істотою:

> 3. Закінчення **-ові** у твердій групі, **-еві** (після голосного та
>    апострофа — **-єві**) у м’якій та мішаній групах мають:
>
>    - іменники чол. роду — переважно назви істот: …

Тобто загалом, все те саме: за основу бажано ***~і***, але через примітки і хитрі певні слова можна через ***~у*** або навіть ***~ові***.

---

Розгляньмо правило про саме чергування.

> [**Чергування приголоснних під час словозміни**](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=21)
>
> **Чергування Г, К, Х із мʼякими З, Ц, С**
>
> **§ 12.** Чергування **г**, **к**, **х** із м’якими **з**, **ц**, **с** відбувається:
>
> 1. У давальному і місцевому відмінках однини іменників жіночого роду першої відміни: …
> 2. У місцевому відмінку однини іменників чоловічого та
>    середнього роду другої відміни: …

Окремо додам і про:

> **Чергування Ґ із мʼяким З**
>
> **§ 13.** **Ґ** чергується з м’яким **з** у давальному і місцевому відмінках однини іменників жіночого роду першої відміни: …

І… на цьому все. Схоже на недопрацювання правопису, що особливо часто стає з ***ґ*** (не лише тут),  оскільки це дозволяє писати щось на зразок *Гамбурґі*, хоча за практикою і тут відбувається заміна з мʼяким ***з***, а за правилами фонетики цілком можливе і ***дз*** (як один звук, дзвінкий варіянт до ***ц***; нагадаю, ***ґ*** — дзвінкий варіянт до ***к***), що ненормативно, але теж практикується [хоч і менше]: *Гамбурдзі*.

До чого ця буква? Бо є окреме правило, що дозволяє писати ***ґ*** замість ***г***. Правда, все ще не для топонімів, але декотрима практикується як ненормативно.

> [**G, H**](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=155)
>
> **§ 122.**
>
> 3. У прізвищах та іменах людей можна передавати звук **[g]**
>    двома способами: шляхом адаптації до звукового ладу української мови — буквою **г** (…) і шляхом імітації іншомовного **[g]** — буквою **ґ** (…).

Comment: Дякую за розлогу відповідь! мені в око впала непослідовність використання закінчень, оскільки і у Вікіпедії склався певний консенсус - чомусь міста на `-бург` приймають закінчення `-у`, а на `-берг` перетворюються на `-берзі`...

Comment: @int21h гадаю, це вже краще питати на самій Вікіпедії.